# When my form is hidden and reloaded from another form it is not executing the code in the Load event

Tags: .net, vb.net

So i have a program from which I am retrieving data from a datagrid and going through the grid one by one but when i close the form using the`Me.Hide` and the reload it again from another form using `frmQuiz.Show` it does  not execute the code in the Load event of the frmQuiz form and as a result it ends up on a record I left on from last time. Here is code from the Load event of the form

```
   Private Sub frmQuiz_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tracker = 0 'to keep track of which record to retrieve from datagrid,in this case the first

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CompLitDataSet.tblQuestions' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblQuestionsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CompLitDataSet.tblQuestions)
    hideGrid()
    dgData.DataSource = TblQuestionsTableAdapter.GetAllUnsorted
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent 'load form at center screen
    ReDim answers(TblQuestionsBindingSource.Count)

    lblQuestion.Text = ""
    lblQuestionNumber.Text = ""
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
    radA.Checked = False
    radB.Checked = False
    radC.Checked = False
    radD.Checked = False

    viewQuestions(0) 'show first questions

End Sub
```

Comment: A simple way to solve your problem is by actually closing the form by using Close() instead of Hide().  Gets your Load event handler to run again *and* avoids wasting machine resources on an invisible window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Me.Hide` just makes the form invisible, it is still loaded in memory and accessible via code.

`Me.Close` unloads the form from memory and is not accessible via code anymore.

Comment: Can yuo back that information about `Me.Close` up with documentation? I was reading about the [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) method and found no remark about that.

Comment: @Renan - Read [MSDN documentation for Form.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx). "When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed.", that sounds like unloaded from memory to me.

Comment: Ok used Me.Close instead of Me.Hide and when I reload everything is alright but one other issue is even though I specify that the data should be retrieved from the first row of the datagrid it starts from the second even after explicitly typing code `lblQuestion.Text = dgData.Rows(0).DataBoundItem("Question").ToString` it still loads the second option.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question and posting the code relevant to your "new" problem. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept it.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I meant about it not being accessible via code anymore, not what it does.

Comment: @Renan - well the instance of the form is disposed so I would think that means not accessible via code, but maybe I am misunderstanding what your interpretation of "available via code" is in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is not being reloaded.

Check the docs: [Form.Load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx)

> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no event for when the form is being hidden or shown - except when it's show for the very first time, which will trigger `Load` and then `Shown`.

There are events for when the form is closing and after it is closed, though. You may want to use those. If the state of the objects related to the form is important for you, you should store those states somewhere you can restore it when the form is recreated.

Comment: +1. `for the first time` is the key here. Although I would better say `before _an instance_ of a form is displayed for the first time`.

Answer (score 1):

It wont fire your Form_Load event because your are "Hiding" your form.
You should Close your form then Show it again.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move code from `Form_Load` handler to [VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) handler instead:

```
Private Sub Form1_VisibleChanged(sender As Object,
                                 e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
  If CType(sender, Form)).Visible = True Then 'your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry can u explain alittle what is going on here

Comment: @Manny264: It makes your code execute when the form was shown after being hidden as well as during a regular form load procedure.