# VB.net opening and closing forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VB program that has two forms, i have coded the form load of each forms.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("I AM FORM 1")
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("I AM FORM 2")
End Sub
```

Here is how i switch through Form1 and Form2, i made use of a button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
```

But everytime i switch forms the form load event will only trigger once. Is there something wrong with my code? I am guesing the Me.Hide() will only hide the previous form and not totally close it. I want to be able to close the previous form so that when i will open it again, the form load event will trigger again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But everytime i switch forms the form load event will only trigger once. Is there something wrong with my code? I am guesing the Me.Hide() will only hide the previous form and not totally close it.

This is exactly what is happening. The `Hide` method just *hides* the form from the user, effectively making it invisible.

What you're looking for is the [`Close` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx), which actually closes the form. (Since you are displaying the form using the `Show` method, you do not need to call `Dispose`.)

You will, however, not be able to close a form and continue to run code in its methods. So you'll need to reverse the order of the statements in your event handler functions, displaying the other form *first* and then closing itself. Make them look like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Close()    
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

That will do what you want. The `Load` event will be triggered each time you call the `Show` method, because you're creating and showing a new form.

It is worth pointing out, though, that you're relying on an unusual characteristic of VB.NET, one that it retains from the older VB languages for backwards compatibility reasons. Instead of referring to an *object* of your form class (like you would have to do with all other class objects), you are referring to it by the *type* name (the name of the class itself). You really shouldn't do that, it causes all sorts of headaches and will confuse people reading your code. It is better to just instantiate a new form object, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New Form1  ' create a new Form1 object
    frm.Show()            ' ... and display it

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm As New Form1  ' create a new Form2 object
    frm.Show()            ' ... and display it

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

When you run this code, you will likely run immediately into another problem: the first time you close `Form1`, your entire application will quit. This is because, by default for a new project, `Form1` is designated as the "Startup form" in your project's properties ("My Project" in the Solution Explorer). You will either have to:

- create a *third* form to use as the "main" form, and set the "Startup form" to this third form, or
- change the "Shutdown mode" (also in "My Project") from "When startup form closes" to "When last form closes".

Comment: Thanks alot it works. Thanks alot for all the additional informations regarding the usage of forms. I couldn't ask for more.

Answer (score 4):

> I am guesing the Me.Hide() will only hide the previous form and not totally close it

Yes, it does what it says.  If you want to close the form then use Me.Close() instead.  The Load event will fire again when you create the new instance.

You'll have to change a setting to ensure that doesn't also close your application.  Project + Properties, Application tab, change the Shutdown mode setting to "When last form closes".  And put the Me.Close() call *after* the Show() call.

Comment: your guide about the Project + Properties, Application tab really saved me. i ddn't know you have to edit something there. I was used with VB6 without having that kind of setting. Thanks alot. I am still adjusting with the VB.net environment

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar question. When u `.Hide()` you are just storing it away in memory somewhere such that when it is re-opened it doesnt have to make a new form just recalls the one from memory hence that method is not called again. You have to destroy the form. So what you can do when navigating to another form is go to that form first and then destroy the current form like so 
 `Form2.Show()`
`Me.Close()`. Look at my question and my accepted answer. If that works please dont forget to tick this as your accepted answer. 
[When my form is hidden and reloaded from another form it is not executing the code in the Load event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927615/when-my-form-is-hidden-and-reloaded-from-another-form-it-is-not-executing-the-co)

Answer (score 0):

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to close this application?", "Close", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
    frmIndex.Show() //the main form 
Else
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.Show() // The form open
End If
```

The form open going closing and going back to the main/index form. hope it help :) just play with the `.show`, .hide and e.cancel

Answer (score -1):

Yes. What you are doing is closing the form before it could open up form2.

### Instead Of:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
```

### You Need To Put:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Form1.show

Me.hide 

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Form2.show

Me.hide   

End Sub
```

If This Helps, Please Reply.

Comment: this will not work at all you have your logic all wrong. it will not make a difference!! #downVote

Comment: This is not correct. `Me.Hide` does *not* close the form, it just hides it. Perhaps you were thinking of `Me.Close`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you using a silly construction, but you should;

```
     Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
          Form1.close()
     End Sub
```

Use the Shown event.

And use ShowDialog()

```
    Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? The `Shown` event is only raised the *first* time that a form is displayed, so it'll work much like `Load`. The only difference is the order in which the two events are raised. And why would you recommend `ShowDialog`? It doesn't sound to me like he wants a blocking modal dialog, so that would be a poor choice.