# Close first form without ending the application / Reassigning new 'Main Form'

Tags: vb.net

My first form is a menu box, when I click on a button I use the following:

```
 Private Sub btn_dbfinder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_dbfinder.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Database.Show()

    End Sub
```

Is there a way to make `Database` the main form so I can close `Me` / `Home` *(not hide)*

The reason is because if a user closes down `Database` it won't end the application, `Home` is just running hidden.

Hope this makes sense.

also - I have tried on google before, but my googling skills are that good today! I should think it's an easy fix? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new form but closing the old one in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491429/how-to-open-a-new-form-but-closing-the-old-one-in-vb)  AndAlso http://stackoverflow.com/q/18286432/1070452

Comment: AndAlso http://stackoverflow.com/q/4976380/1070452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the properties of the project to select "When last form closes" in the shutdown mode dropdown

Update:-

```
"Project" menu -> 'YourApp' Properties... -> Application Tab
```

find : "Shutdown Mode"

Change from

```
"When startup form closes" --> "When last form closes"
```

Comment: Just did this, but because the form is still hidden, isn't it still active?

Comment: Dont hide it, close it as suggested by your title and explained in the Dupe links

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, I was having a Blonde moment.- This works now.

Not sure why this is downvoted though? :S

Answer (score -1):

You should first show the form you want to open, after that you can close your other form.

try this :

```
Database.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

Comment: I want to close the home form not hide it. If I hide it, the user has to open it back up to end the application. - This question was edited.

Comment: try this: Me.Close()

Comment: If I do me.close() it will close the whole program down.